# Typecast a ArrayList.toArray() in Java to normal array

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I'm having some trouble to do the following:

```
int[] tmpIntList = (int[])MyArrayList.toArray(someValue);
```

MyArrayList contains only numbers. I get a typecast error since `ArrayList` only returns `Object[]` but why isnt it possible to turn it into a `int[]` ?

Comment: what do you need it for? Collections are best kept as Collection classes... unless there is a need to optimise, but then you have to be sure that you are not optimising prematurely (an ArrayList is almost as fast an an array)

Comment: Thats correct, but in this case I need to have a int[] to return for another function that only takes int[]. (not built by me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `ArrayList` can't contain `int` values, as it's backed by an `Object[]` (even when appropriately generic).

The closest you could come would be to have an `Integer[]` - which can't be cast to an `int[]`. You have to convert each element separately. I believe there are libraries which implement these conversions for all the primitive types.

Basically the problem is that Java generics don't support primitive types.

Answer (score 3):

[`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) will do the conversion between `Integer[]` and `int[]`, if you really need it. (apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi))

So:

```
int[] tmpIntList = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(MyArrayList.toArray(someValue));
```

Comment: Upvoted for giving Commons Lang as a solution, it has a utility method for pretty much everything you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then including apache-commons for only this single method call, you can use 
`Integer[]` .

@Bozho , thanks mate for this suggestion.